# <dt> and <dd> not appended

Tags: javascript, html

I really don't understand why the dt and dd are not created not added to the dl I created. This is the first way I tried:

```
    // Liste des mots du dictionnaire
var mots = [
    {
        terme: "Procrastination",
        definition: "Tendance pathologique à remettre systématiquement au lendemain"
    },
    {
        terme: "Tautologie",
        definition: "Phrase dont la formulation ne peut être que vraie"
    },
    {
        terme: "Oxymore",
        definition: "Figure de style qui réunit dans un même syntagme deux termes sémantiquement opposés"
    }
];
// TODO : créer le dictionnaire sur la page web, dans la div "contenu"
var divEtl = document.getElementById("contenu");
var dlEtl = document.createElement("dl");

for (var i = 0; i < mots.length; i++) {

    var termeEtl = document.createElement("dt");
    var definitionEtl = document.createElement("dd");

    var termeTextnode = document.createTextNode(mots[i].terme.toString());
    var definitionTextnode = document.createTextNode(mots[i].definition.toString());

    dlEtl.appendChild(termeEtl.appendChild(termeTextnode));
    dlEtl.appendChild(definitionEtl.appendChild(definitionTextnode));
}
divEtl.appendChild(dlEtl);
```

and the result in HTML is :

```
<div id="contenu"><dl>ProcrastinationTendance pathologique à remettre systématiquement au lendemainTautologiePhrase dont la formulation ne peut être que vraieOxymoreFigure de style qui réunit dans un même syntagme deux termes sémantiquement opposés</dl></div>
```

I also tried a different way, it created the dt and dd but then I had trouble showing the termes and definitions.

```
var dl = document.createElement("dl");

for (var term in mots) {
    var dt = document.createElement("dt");
    var dd = document.createElement("dd");

    dt.innerHTML = mots.terme;
    dd.innerHTML = mots.definition;

    dl.appendChild(dt);
    dl.appendChild(dd);
}

divEtl.appendChild(dl);
```

the dt and dd tags are filled with "undefined" ... 
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) says the appendChild return the child itself, not the parent. Change the code this way to pass dt and dd to the dl.

```
termeEtl.appendChild(termeTextnode) ;
definitionEtl.appendChild(definitionTextnode) ;

dlEtl.appendChild(termeEtl);
dlEtl.appendChild(definitionEtl);
```

When we iterate mots array the `term` will be filled with array index, so the data can be accessed as `mots[term].terme`.

```
for (var term in mots) {
    ...
    dt.innerHTML = mots[term].terme;
    dd.innerHTML =  mots[term].definition;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't try this because I thought it doesn't change anything. Now I see that we have to separates to operation. I still don't  understand what I was doing but thank you!

Comment: What about the other way what do you think I should do to access the attributes of each object?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct except appendings in the for-loop. You're appending nothing to d1Et1 since appendChild doesn't return that parent.

Try it like this,

```
    // Liste des mots du dictionnaire
var mots = [
    {
        terme: "Procrastination",
        definition: "Tendance pathologique à remettre systématiquement au lendemain"
    },
    {
        terme: "Tautologie",
        definition: "Phrase dont la formulation ne peut être que vraie"
    },
    {
        terme: "Oxymore",
        definition: "Figure de style qui réunit dans un même syntagme deux termes sémantiquement opposés"
    }
];
// TODO : créer le dictionnaire sur la page web, dans la div "contenu"
var divEtl = document.getElementById("contenu");
var dlEtl = document.createElement("dl");

for (var i = 0; i < mots.length; i++) {

    var termeEtl = document.createElement("dt");
    var definitionEtl = document.createElement("dd");

    var termeTextnode = document.createTextNode(mots[i].terme.toString());
    var definitionTextnode = document.createTextNode(mots[i].definition.toString());

    termeEtl.appendChild(termeTextnode);
    definitionEtl.appendChild(definitionTextnode);
    dlEtl.appendChild(termeEtl);
    dlEtl.appendChild(definitionEtl);
}
divEtl.appendChild(dlEtl);
```

Comment: Thank you, but what about the other way, how can I access the attributes of each object? It says undefined